# Java library to find parametric solutions to a linear algebra system with singular matrix

Tags: java, linear-algebra, solution, solver, singular

I would like to solve in Java this integer linear algebra problem, where xi, yi, zi are the integer variables (all positive, xi≥0, yi≥0, zi≥0),
and a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h are the constants (positive integers ≥0, for example a=20, b=12, c=28, d=24, e=19, f=5, g=6, h=6).

```
x1+x2+x3+x4+x5 = a
y1+y2+y3+y4+y5 = b
z1+z2+z3+z4+z5 = c
x1+y1+z1 = d
x2+y2+z2 = e
x3+y3+z3 = f
x4+y4+z4 = g
x5+y5+z5 = h


It could be viewed as:
 - sum constraint on the rows
 - sum constraint on the columns

 | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | → sum equal to a
 | y1 | y2 | y3 | y4 | y5 | → sum equal to b
 | z1 | z2 | z3 | z4 | z5 | → sum equal to c
   ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓
   d    e    f    g    h
```

Obviously there are a moltitude of integer solutions to this problem (but not unlimited). If it is possible I would like to easily collect a bunch of these integer solutions an randomly pop one on these from the collection.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Solved (it finds a single solution):**

Thanks to apete! I found a solution to this problem using [ojalgo](https://code.google.com/p/ojalgo/).
Here is my code:

```
import org.ojalgo.OjAlgoUtils;
import org.ojalgo.netio.BasicLogger;
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Expression;
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.ExpressionsBasedModel;
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Optimisation;
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Variable;

/**
 * @author madx
 */
public abstract class ojAlgoTest {

    static int[] row_constraints = new int[]{20,12,28};
    static int[] col_constraints = new int[]{24,19,5,6,6};

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        BasicLogger.debug();
        BasicLogger.debug(ojAlgoTest.class.getSimpleName());
        BasicLogger.debug(OjAlgoUtils.getTitle());
        BasicLogger.debug(OjAlgoUtils.getDate());
        BasicLogger.debug();

        int rows = row_constraints.length;
        int cols = col_constraints.length;

        // Create variables expressing servings of each of the considered variable
        // Set lower and upper limits on the number of servings as well as the weight (cost of a
        // serving) for each variable.
        final Variable matrix[][] = new Variable[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0; i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                matrix[i][j] = Variable.make("Matrix" + i + "_" + j).lower(0).upper(24).weight(1);
            }
        }

        // Create a model and add the variables to it.
        final ExpressionsBasedModel tmpModel = new ExpressionsBasedModel();
        for(int i=0; i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                tmpModel.addVariable(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // Create contraints

        for(int i=0; i<cols;i++){
            final Expression cat = tmpModel.addExpression("Col_Constraint_"+i).lower(col_constraints[i]).upper(col_constraints[i]);
            for(int j=0; j<rows;j++){
                cat.setLinearFactor(matrix[j][i], 1);
            }
        }

        for(int j=0; j<rows;j++){
            final Expression cat = tmpModel.addExpression("Row_Constraint_"+j).lower(row_constraints[j]).upper(row_constraints[j]);
            for(int i=0; i<cols;i++){
                cat.setLinearFactor(matrix[j][i], 1);
            }
        }

        // Solve the problem - minimise the cost
        Optimisation.Result tmpResult = tmpModel.minimise();

        // Print the result
        BasicLogger.debug();
        BasicLogger.debug(tmpResult);
        BasicLogger.debug();

        // Modify the model to require an integer valued solution.
        BasicLogger.debug("Adding integer constraints...");
        for(int i=0; i<rows;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
                matrix[i][j].integer(true);
            }
        }

        // Solve again
        tmpResult = tmpModel.minimise();

        // Print the result, and the model
        BasicLogger.debug();
        BasicLogger.debug(tmpResult);
        BasicLogger.debug();
        BasicLogger.debug(tmpModel);
        BasicLogger.debug();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? SO is for answering specific questions, post what you have tried so far. This appears to be homework.

Comment: And it's totally OK if it's homework but we need to see your work so far.

Comment: Of course it is not homework, I'm looking for a library that can help me with this, I don't want to reinvent the wheel...
However I simply tried with http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html, but it doesn't help with a singular matrix, I think...

Comment: Maybe I could solve this in real space, find the hyperplane parametric solution and then pass to find some integer solution, but I think there exists a more easy way. And also if I could reach this I don't know/find any Java library for doing this, I hope in your libs knowledge

Comment: I don't know about Java libraries, but programs like Matlab can solve systems of equations.  I also know there are algorithms that can be applied in Java, something like Gaussian Elimination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot this be formulated as a network flow problem? (a flow from the column constraints to the row constraints with an extra row/column to handle the difference) If this is true then the network simplex algorithm can be used to produce integer solutions (all problem parameters must be integers).

If I'm wrong, it can definitely be formulated as a general MIP problem. There are many free and commercial software packages that can help solve such. One open source pure Java alternative (that I wrote) is ojAlgo.

[Here's an example](https://code.google.com/p/ojalgo/wiki/TheDietProblem) on how to model optimization problems using ojAlgo.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! I pasted my code in the question above! I reached this with your ojalgo lib!
Just one more question.
I easily managed to obtain a single solution to this problem (it returns me always the same solution with the same constraints)... But my target was to find randomly one of the solutions that respected the constraints... In that sense all solutions would have the same target_cost, and use optimization is maybe more than needed. However is there a way to get more than one solution to the problem? Or it returns only the first with minimal cost?

Comment: Randomize the weights to obtain a random solution seems a overkill, maybe the tool provides some other methods...

Comment: ojAlgo has no way to give you all (or several) solutions to a MIP. The only thing you can do is to alter the variable weights (don't rebuild the entire model, just update the weights) and solve again. Resolving with different weights, but with a known integer solution as a starting point should be much faster than solving a new model from scratch.